# Questions on a nonreduced scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading [*Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf) by Ravi Vakil.

On page 131, the author says,

> We should picture $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$ in terms of the information the quotient remembers.
>   The image of a polynomial $f(x)$ is the information of its value at $0$, and its derivative.

The author gives a hint as to understanding this. This hint is: for $f(x) \in \mathbb C[x]$, what is $f(x+\varepsilon)$ in $\mathbb C[x,\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$? I think this is $f(x) +f'(x)\varepsilon$. But this knowledges fails to give me enough light. So would anyone please explain to me the meaning of

> The image of a polynomial $f(x)$ is the information of its value at $0$, and its derivative.

More exactly, how is the information given?

6.3.11 on page 184 is *picturing maps of schemes when nilpotents are present*. The picture of $\text{Spec}\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$ is a point with a "fuzz", and the picture of $\text{Spec}\mathbb C[x]$ is a line plus a generic point. Let the morphism from one to the other be corresponding to the ring homomorphism $\mathbb C[x] \rightarrow \mathbb C[x]/(x^2),x \mapsto ax$
for $a \in \mathbb C$. Then for $a =0$ and $a \neq 0$, how does the pictures of the morphisms of schemes differ? Does the happens on the "fuzz", and why?

I think better conderstanding on these problems may clear many of my confusions on nonreduced schemes. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, the fact that $f(x+\epsilon) = f(x)+f'(x)\epsilon \pmod{\epsilon^2}$ tells you that a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{C}[x,\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ vanishes iff $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are both zero. Now suppose that $f\in\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is a "function" on $X = \text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ - which is a "shred" of the line $\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$ around the point $(x)$. Identify $(x)$ with the point $x=0$ of this line. To say that $f$ vanishes on $X$ means that (a) $f(0) = 0$ and (b) $f'(0) = 0$ since $f = a_0 + a_1 x \pmod{x^2}$. (continued) ...

Comment: Therefore $X = \text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ looks like the point $(x)$ on $\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$ except that it also detects the "tangent lines" of polynomial functions passing through $(x)$ i.e. their derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(X)$ be a polynomial, the image of $P(X)$ in $Spec(C[X]/(X^2)$ is equivalent to the image of $P(0)+P'(0)X$ where $P'$ is the derivative of $P$.